# Immediate editing of comments causes them to show as edited

Tags: feature-request, comments, edits

Why is this? Sometimes I want to make an immediate formatting or grammatical change, but I end up deleting and leaving a new comment.

Comment: ...why wouldn't it?

Comment: That is editing, its fair it shows up as such. Don't worry about edits,  I really don't understand why people worry about them. Edits are good, they show you care about the qualit of even comments

Comment: @RichardTingle Better edit that comment for spelling! Unless you don't care ;)

Comment: @RichardTingle, edits can make you appear intellectually dishonest in discussions since, for comments, the history isn't presented.

Comment: "Intellectually dishonest"? I don't follow. The edit symbol is simply a signal for anyone who read the comment before, and might wonder why it suddenly says something else.

Comment: @Pëkka, neither part of which applies to instant, minor edits.

Comment: @MikeGraham How do you know that instant edits are minor?

Comment: @Pëkka It can come from me saying something like, "this post isn't well researched", your responding, "yeah, I agree with @servy", and then me editing my post to say, "this post is very thoroughly researched".  Of course, outside of joking/messing around on meta, I never really see people do this, nor do I see people concerned (other than apparently this user) that this is going on whenever a comment is marked as edited.  The same idea applies to comment upvotes.  I can comment "kill all teh unicorns", get 50 upvotes, then edit it to "I <3 unicorns" and make it seem like meta loves unicorns.

Comment: Pencil irony ... -->

Comment: @RobertHarvey, I appreciate you feel that way, but this is no place for namecalling.

Comment: I'm perplexed why this feature is treated as so strange when it's already implemented for Answers. 

It's a very common feature present not only in Stack Exchange, but in vBulletin, reddit, etc.

Answer (score 8):

It is an edit so you it makes sense it shows up as one

Don't worry about being seen to edit, frankly I pay no attention to the pencil mark. If anything they show you care about the quality of even comments.

The only time it would even be an issue is if people appeared to be agreeing to a clearly ridiculous statement. But I've never seen it come up. Comments are supposed to be short lived, if there's anything that needs to have a clear provenance a comment is probably the wrong place for it.